# Push Notification working in Development But not In Distribution

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a small issue with my app Apple push notifications are working fine in Development But not in Distribution. I don't know why please help me out in this

Thanks in advance

Comment: It could be that you left `sandbox` in server address. There is really not much info in the question.

Comment: It could be because you are not using distribution push certificate. Here is the link of very nice tutorial, order of the steps are also important while generating the distribution profile. http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the following scenarios and execute.

1. In the firewalls need to check the 2195, 2196 ports and also check gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, gateway.push.apple.com
2. Sign your application using distribution profiles and run the application in distribution mode. Make sure if you are running the application using distribution mode then in server side also should use distribution PEM files. I believe you are made the mistake in this scenario.